# How to remove Spin Doctor tile spacers

Tags: tile

We used the Spin Doctor tile spacer and leveler for our shower tile. It's really nice to keep things all level.

Now we are having trouble breaking off the spacers. The things I've seen online indicate that they should break off very nicely. When we use a hammer, the spacers don't break cleanly at the level of the tile. Are there any tips for this?

Comment: Are you knocking them out with the caps intact?   I have never had a problem when hitting the caps with a rubber hammer, or even kicking them.

Comment: @RMDman Yes. That doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Same.  Use a rubber mallet or kick them.  Note, IIRC they're flat, so if you're having trouble breaking them off cleanly, try rotating 90º and them from that direction.

Comment: Please link to your specific product or show us a photo. Most of us aren't familiar with that particular brand.